# Search on Custom ListView Android error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have app where I should implement search on Custom List so I have error when I type any key on edittext`01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer.CustomList.getView(CustomList.java:52)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2054)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1476)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1339)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5005)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5005)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:762)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5005)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5005)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2141)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12948)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1227)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2695)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-26 21:19:11.441: E/AndroidRuntime(5793):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

My activity:`

```
public class MyLibrary extends Fragment {
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
CustomList adapter;
EditText inputSearch;
int textlength = 0;

public MyLibrary() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Parse.initialize(getActivity(),
            "ASD",
            "ASD");
    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.getnewlay, container, false);

    new RemoteDataTask().execute();

    return view;
}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Simple ListView Tutorial");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("BookStore");
        query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
        try {
            ob = query.find();
            Log.e("Yes", "" + ob);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listviewget);
        inputSearch = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        adapter = new CustomList(getActivity(), ob);

        /*
         * ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item);
         */
        // Retrieve object "name" from Parse.com database
        for (ParseObject country : ob) {
            adapter.add((String) country.get("name"));
        }
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            ArrayList<String> text_sort = new ArrayList<String>();

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
            //adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());
                String text = inputSearch.getText().toString()
                        .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);
                /*
                 * adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString()); textlength =
                 * inputSearch.getText().length(); text_sort.clear();
                 */
                // image_sort.clear();

                /*
                 * for (int i = 0; i < text_sort.size(); i++) { if
                 * (textlength <= ob.get(i).size()) { if
                 * (edittext.getText().toString(). equalsIgnoreCase((String)
                 * text[i].subSequence(0, textlength))) {
                 * text_sort.add(text[i]); image_sort.add(image[i]); } }
                 */

            }
        });
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        /*
         * listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         * 
         * @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View
         * view, int position, long id) { // Send single item click data to
         * SingleItemView Class // Intent i = new Intent(GetNewBooks.this,
         * // SingleItemView.class); // Pass data "name" followed by the
         * position // i.putExtra("name", ob.get(position).getString("name")
         * // .toString()); // Open SingleItemView.java Activity //
         * startActivity(i); } });
         */
    }
}


}
```

AdapretClass:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter < String > {
private finalActivity context;
/*private final String[] web;
private final String[] descr;
private final Integer[] imageId;
private final Integer[] imagId;*/
private List < ParseObject > ob = null;
//  private final String[] descr;
// public CustomList(Activity context, List<ParseObject>
// ob,List<ParseObject> ob2) {
// }
private ArrayList < ParseObject > arraylist;
public CustomList(Activity context, List < ParseObject > ob) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_single);
    this.ob = ob;
    this.context = context;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList < ParseObject > ();
    this.arraylist.addAll(ob);
    //  this.descr = ob;
    /*this.descr = ob2;
    this.web = ob;
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.imagId = imagId;*/
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lname);
    //for(ParseObject i : ob) txtTitle.setText((CharSequence) i);
    txtTitle.setText(ob.get(position).get("name").toString());
    return rowView;
}

public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    ob.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        ob.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (ParseObject wp: arraylist) {
            if (((String) wp.get("name")).toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                .contains(charText)
            ) {
                ob.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: What is line number 52 in CustomList?

Comment: txtTitle.setText( ob.get(position).get("name").toString());

Comment: @EagleEye but it works until I type any key

Comment: Correct. problem is your both if conditions are not satisfying the condition in filter() method. You are doing ob.clear() where all elements will be removed from list. so there are no elements when you try to search in list. Put some log statements and check whether if statement is true or not.

Comment: @EagleEye I am just following this tutorial http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/ but he is use clear()

Comment: No issues in that. i m telling you to check whether if conditions are satisfied or not both in if and else statements. Can you do that and let me know?

Comment: @EagleEye please can you wait a minute I will check it

Comment: @EagleEye work only else

Comment: in else part again inside for loop the if condition is not working check that also and modify the condition accordingly.

Comment: @EagleEye   it is also not working

Comment: Thats what I m telling from 1st comment itself. Your if condition is not working properly and its not adding any values. There are no "ParseObject" has a name with a character you have entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you got `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception. Why?

1. Your `CustomList` is **`String`** `ArrayAdapter` and you initialize number of item in your adapter as below:

```
for (ParseObject country : ob) {
    adapter.add((String) country.get("name"));
}
```

--> that means your `adapter` has `ob.size()` = 2 items, right?

2. After you `filter` your adapter, your `ob.size()` is changed (smaller than 2 item, I guest) however, your `String` `ArrayAdapter` doesn't change (still has 2 items) --> the `getView()` function will throw in line `txtTitle.setText(ob.get(position).get("name").toString());`

If you want to solve it change your `filter` as below:

```
 public void filter(String charText) {
charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
ob.clear();
this.clear(); // clear the adapter too.

if (charText.length() == 0) {
    ob.addAll(arraylist);
} else {
    for (ParseObject wp: arraylist) {
        if (((String) wp.get("name")).toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
            .contains(charText)
        ) {
            ob.add(wp);
            this.add((String)wp.get("name")); // add item to your adapter.            
        }
    }
}
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

P/s: Your adapter is really ugly. You should learn how to reuse in `getView`. It will improve your list scroll performance a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much do you think I should use Base Adapter or just holders

Comment: @Sultan I prefer using `ArrayAdapter`. However, you should use `ParseObject` instead of `String` in your `CustomeAdapter`.